# Callback injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, services, circular-dependency, callbacks

I have a service that needs to make a callback. Basically, it is an event that is expected to be handled in exactly one place, and that is too important to be optional.

The obvious approach seems to be to inject an `Action`. **In the context of dependency injection, is it considered good (or acceptable) practice to do so?**

I'm also eager to hear **why (not)**, or what **alternatives** you would consider.

One particular problem that comes to mind is in the following scenario:

- `Parent`'s constructor takes an `IChild`.
- `Child`'s constructor takes an `Action`, the callback.
- `Parent` has the method that is to receive the callback.
- To instantiate the `Child`, we need the `Parent`'s method, and thus the `Parent` instance. But to create that, we first need the `Child` instance. Problem.

One solution I can think of is to inject an `IChildFactory` instead. `Parent`'s constructor can then use that factory to create the `Child` instance. At this point, `Parent` exists, and thus it can pass its callback method to the factory.

This solution seems to get the job done, but I'm curious about alternatives.

Comment: Once you're injecting a dependency as an abstraction (whether an object or function/method pointer), IMO it is an acceptable approach and you're able to get the benefits of DI. However, I would create an Interface and inject some implementation of it into your service. I think this would break even more any coupling between service and its client. Some frameworks can select implementations based on configuration file, and if some signature changes, you can easily find the right place to modify them.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I thought I'd added the C# tag! Now I have.

Comment: @EmersonCardoso I do believe that the same problem remains in my example: `Parent` needs `Child`, but `Child` needs `Parent` (which implements the interface you mention). How would you tackle this?

Comment: @Timo, you're right, the circular dependencies still exist regardless of the approach. About that, I'm confused about the following: (i) _Parent has the method that is to receive the callback._, and (ii) _To instantiate the Child, we need the Parent's method_. If the callback is implemented in the child, what does it mean that the `Parent` "receives the method" ? I don't understand that part..

Comment: @EmersonCardoso Let's say the `Child` wants to call some log method, and `Parent` wants to dictate how logging is done. This would require us to pass `Parent`'s `Log()` method (or `Parent` itself) to `Child`'s constructor, thus creating the circular dependency.

Comment: well, can't you define a ILogger interface, and property-inject it into the Child instance? Like this, you break circular dependency.

Comment: @EmersonCardoso If the `Parent` *is* the one implementing that interface, the problem remains unchanged. A separate logger would not pose this problem, of course.

Comment: what I suggested whats injecting the `ILogger` (implemented by `Parent`) via property instead of a constructor.

Comment: @EmersonCardoso Sorry, I misread. Let me post your suggestion as an answer so that it can be discussed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did I not think of this before?

We can simply inject into `Parent`'s constructor a `Func<Parent, Child>`, a function that takes the `Parent` as a parameter and returns the [new] `Child`. (Alternatively, the function could accept the callback method instead of the entire parent - the idea is the same.)

In `Parent`'s constructor, `Parent` exists, so it can pass [part of] itself to the function that creates `Child`. Then, it can assign the created `Child` to its read-only property.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, injecting a callback is absolutely acceptable. I would usually prefer to do it this way.

An alternative, which you've already pointed out, is to define an event on the service object and use a factory to create it - making sure that it's the *only* way to create it and then have the factory handle the event, or delegate it further (which brings us back to square one).<sup>*</sup>

The specific parent/child example may have other solutions, depending on your context. For example, you could create the parent, and pass it to the child constructor, which could insert itself as the parent's child.

<sub>* Clarification: My suggestion was to *either* inject a callback *or* use a factory that registers an event handler in the regular way. In this case, to enforce your requirement that the event **must** be handled, only the factory should create service objects. Then no-one can create a service object without registering an event handler.</sub>

<sub>You may want to use a factory even with the injected callback for other reasons (e.g. to make sure the *correct* callback is provided). Also you may have multiple such factories. Those are separate considerations.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! I would not have the child insert itself on the parent, as I prefer to stick with readonly properties.

Comment: What is the reason for making sure the factory is the *only* way to instantiate the service?

Comment: @Timo I can't answer for doubleYou, but I suppose it would not be important if there is one or several factories.  The point being that you use dependency injection in a factory separate from the service, as the service should not also *create* the callback (it should be decoupled from the action taken afterwards).

Comment: See my edits, I hope they answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

As per EmersonCardoso's comment, we might inject the Parent into the Child via property injection:

- Child is injected into Parent, by constructor injection.
- In Parent's constructor, it sets itself on one of Child's properties.

This helps deal with the cyclic nature of the dependencies. The solution is much like having a public event property, except for only a single handler.

Disadvantages might be:

- The dependency has become (compile-time) optional.
- Child has become stateful. Stateless services are a good practice anyway, and even more so in DDD, for example.
- Child has become externally mutable. Even if statefulness is deemed acceptable, external mutability is something I would avoid.